# JMS Priority Messages Causing Starvation of Lower Priority Message

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, businessworks

I have a queue that is loaded with high priority JMS messages throughout the day, I want to get them out the door quickly.  The queue is also being loaded periodically with lower priority messages in large batches.  The problem that I see on busy days, is that there are always enough high priority messages at the front of the queue that none of the lower priority messages get selected until that volume drops off.  Often they will sit on the queue until they middle of the night.  The app is distributed over a number of servers, but the CPUs are not even breathing hard, the JMS seems to be the choak point.

My hunch is to implement some sort of aging algorithm that increases priority for messages that have been on the queue for a very long time, but of course, that is what middleware is supposed to do for me.  I can't imagine that the JMS provider (IBM WebsphereMQ) or the application server (TIBCO BusinessWorks) doesn't have some sort of facility to cope with this.  So before I go write some code, I thought I would ask, is there any way to get either of these technologies to help me out with this problem?

The BusinessWorks activity that is reading the queue is a JMS SOAP Event Source, but I could turn it into a JMS Queue Receiver activity or whatever.

All thoughts on how to solve this are welcome :-) TIA

Comment: I would think it's also worth reviewing exactly what is the choke point of the system. You site CPUs are not in being used much. So is the system disk or network bound? 

Rather than trying and move message priorities has consideration been given to increase the number of consumers? To keep up with the production of messages?

Answer (score 1):

That's like tying 1 hand behind your back and then complaining that you cannot swim properly. D'oh!  First off, who's bright idea was it to mix messages.  Just because you can do something does not mean you should.

> The app is distributed over a number of servers, but the CPUs are not
>   even breathing hard, the JMS seems to be the choak point.

Well then, the solution is easy.  Put high priority messages into queue "A" (the existing queue) and low priority messages into a new queue "B".  Next, startup another instance of your JMS application to read the messages off queue "B".

Also, JMS is probably not the choke-point.  It is what the application is doing with the message data after the JMS layer picks up the message that is taking a long time (i.e. backend work).

Finally, how many instances of your JMS application is running against the existing queue?  If you are only running 1 instance, why?  If you have lots of CPU capacity then why don't you run 10 instances of your JMS application.  Do some true parallel processing of messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep you messages mixed on the same queue and have the high priority messages processed first, and yet your volume of messages is such that you cannot work through all the volume sometimes until the middle of the night, then you quite simply do not have enough processing applications. MQ is a parallel processing system, it is designed to allow many applications to put or get from a queue at once. Make use of this by running more of your getting applications at the same time. They will work through your high priority messages quicker and then get back to processing the lower priority ones.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it's clear that you want the high priority messages to processed first. In such a case lower priority messages will have to wait.

MQ will not increase the priority of messages if they are sitting in queue for long time. How will it know that it has to change property of a message :)?. You will need to develop an application to do that.

I would think segregating messages based on priority, for example, high priority messages are put to one queue and lower priority messages to another queue could be one option you could look at.

Second option would be to look at the changing the delivery sequence (MSGDLVSQ) to FIFO. This makes to messages to be delivered to consumers in the order they arrived into queue. But note this will ignore the message priority, meaning if there is a lower priority message followed by a higher priority message, then higher priority message will wait till the lower priority message is delivered.